# When creating a SQL table, why or why not use the CONSTRAINT keyword?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

For example in the last line of the following create table statement, instead of writing CONSTRAINT PK_food PRIMARY KEY (food_numb), couldn't I have just done PRIMARY KEY(food_numb)?? What is the purpose of the CONSTRAINT keyword?

```
CREATE TABLE food
(
  food_numb integer,
  food_description varchar (256)
  source_numb integer,
  amount integer,
  CONSTRAINT PK_food PRIMARY KEY (food_numb)
)
```

Comment: There are other types of constraints besides primary key which _do_ require using `CONSTRAINT` syntax.  In the case of primary key, you have two options.

Answer (score 2):

We normally use constraint for primary key when we take a composite primary key

eg:

> CONSTRAINT PK_Food PRIMARY KEY (food_num,food_description)

In this case you have two options. There are many other types of constraints which you really do have to use **CONSTRAINT** keyword.

Refer this for more [mysql constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html)

Comment: What about using foreign keys, do you recommend using Constraint fk_example xyz references table1(id)? Something like that? Or no need for the constraint keyword as well

Comment: If you don't create constraint. It will automatically create its own constraint name. The use of constraint allows you to assign a specific name to the foreign key constraint. This can be used to make error messages easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You **must** specify CONSTRAINT name if you want to refer to it further. For example, for its deletion.

You may skip CONSTRAINT keyword (and, of course, its name) and allow MySQL to generate the name automatically always, but do this only if you have no plans to refer to the constraint name in future.

You can always look for the constraint name (both specified explicitly and generated automatically) using `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statement.

It is not reasonable to use CONSTRAINT clause for PRIMARY KEY - this is an exclusion, the name specified will be ignored, and predefined name `PRIMARY` will be used anycase. This is documented.